# Too Many Values To Unpack While Rendering Data On A Template (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-orm

### VIEWS

```css
def Aeging(request):
    current_date_thirty = date.today().isoformat()
    days_before_thirty = (date.today() - timedelta(days=30)).isoformat()

    thirty = journalVoucher.objects.values('account_name_one').order_by('account_name_one').filter(voucher_date_one__range=[days_before_thirty,current_date_thirty]).annotate(outstanding=(Sum('credit_amount_one')-Sum('debit_amount_one')))
    for item in thirty:
        item['account_name_one'] = CreateLedger.objects.get(id=item['account_name_one'])
        return thirty
        
    context ={'thirty':thirty}
    return render(request,'report/aeging/aeging_analysis.html',context)
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="table-responsive col-md-6">

    <table id="example" class="table table-bordered">
        <caption style="caption-side:top; text-align: center;"><h3>0-30 Days</h3></caption>
        <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            {#  <th>S No.</th>#}
                <th>Party Name</th>
                <th>Total Amount</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for item in thirty %}
            <tr class="table-success">
            {#  <td>{{  }}&nbsp;</td>#}
                <td>{{item.account_name_one}}</td>
                <td>{{ item.outstanding }}&nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
                <tfoot>
            <tr class="totalColumn">
                <td style="visibility:hidden;"></td>
                <td>Total:</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    </div>

</div>
    </div>
```

Hi The Query Is perfectly Run on python shell but when i render the data on a template it shows too many values to unpack (expected 2).
I Provide You My Views and Template Code.

Any Solution Of This??

Images Link..
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1V7uI4YS4Qg8ng4bmN0aCFvp85Dzi8n5S?usp=sharing

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: where is the rest of `Traceback` - on image you shows only beginning of page with error but it seems there are more information which could show where is problem.

Comment: @furas  Hey U can check out error images on the given link.

Comment: I also see that images and i dont think it shows error on any line

Comment: And Don't Mark this question Unuseful.

Comment: I will repeat: always put full error message as text (not screenshot). And don't expect that people will visit your link to see some screenshot - there are many other questions with full errors as text and people will prefer to answer for other questions.

Comment: Bro are u checking that link

Comment: I am new on stackoverflow and i dont know how to upload multiple images

Comment: If u dont know just okay

Comment: How can i put this image error as a text its too long

Comment: I checked link but I was many images and I resign to check them.

Comment: Put only text from `Traceback` without `Request Information`. I checked images and `Traceback` is only on two images.

Comment: Now are u able to answer if u see the screenshot